# Enabling or installing blowfish2 capabilities on VIM 7.4.52

Tags: installing, security

I've read that blowfish2 encryption is available on VIM 7.4.399. For some reason, my version—7.4.52—does not have blowfish2 capabilities (it has blowfish capabilities, though).

I used `sudo apt install vim-gnome` to install VIM. Is there a vimball or something of the sort I can use to enable blowfish2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the command you mention includes `apt` I suppose you're on debian or a linux distribution based on it (ubuntu, mint).

I've looked on ubuntu's website and found a [vim-gnome](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vim-gnome) package for the latest LTS (14.04).

Its version is 7.4.052 which is not enough if blowfish2 support was added in version 7.4.399.

If you're on ubuntu 14.04, to install a more recent version of vim-gnome, you could add [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) to the list of your repositories :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pi-rho/dev
```

Then update and upgrade.

The latest version of vim-gnome from this ppa is 7.4.899, which should be enough.

Since there are different versions of vim, with different features (vim-tiny, vim-gnome ...), you could also check that you're calling the desired version by typing :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vim
```

Comment: Ah! Your solution worked perfectly, thank you. My VIM screen says "7.4.52," but, as you said—the version is actually 7.4.052. Might this be a [very] small bug?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If the package name includes the zero but not the version reported inside your program, it's a bit misleading, I agree with you.